# Javascript Object.prototype is undefined

Tags: javascript, oop, class, object

I'm trying to create a simple extensible "class" in javascript but when setting property in a prototype it tells that the prototype is undefined:

```
Class = {};
Class.extend = function(obj) {
    var result = Object.create(this);

    if (obj) {
        for (var key in obj) {
          if(typeof obj[key] == 'function'){
            console.log(result);
            result.protorype[key] = obj[key];
          }else{
            result[key] = obj[key];
          };
        };

        result.prototype.constructor = result;
    }

    return result;

}

var a = Class.extend({
    username: "matteo",
    password: "nn te la dico",
    getByUsername: function() {
        return this.username;
    }
});



console.log(a, Class.isPrototypeOf(a));​
```

The problem happens when trying to set the property 'getByUsername' passed when defining "a", if you look at the console it will report that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'getByUsername' of undefined
```

And the "result" logged has the properties "username" and "password".

P.S It will work only in IE > 8

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/paglia_s/z62eA/

Comment: `result.protorype[key] = obj[key];` or `result.prototype[key] = obj[key];` ?

Comment: @HackedByChinese no it has been built by hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't create your object by using :
    Class = {};

But by using :
    Class = function(){};

Which creates a new object with a prototype..

Your code will look like so :

```
Class = function(){};

Class.extend = function(obj) {
    var result = Object.create(this);

    if (obj) {
        for (var key in obj) {
          if(typeof obj[key] == 'function'){
            console.log(result);
            result.prototype[key] = obj[key];
          }else{
            result[key] = obj[key];
          };
        };

        result.prototype.constructor = result;
    }

    return result;

}

var a = Class.extend({
    username: "matteo",
    password: "nn te la dico",
    getByUsername: function() {
        return this.username;
    }
});


console.log(a, Class.isPrototypeOf(a));​
```

Comment: see the console here http://jsfiddle.net/paglia_s/z62eA/3/, "a" works correctly but then in "b" username isn't overriden because the original one is inside the proto

Comment: In my console a has password and username properties and the prototype. For b i get the username and the prototype. For c i get the prototype (inherited function) and for d i get username and in the proto username and password (coming from a) and the prototype (getByUsername and getto).. It's not what you want ?

Comment: for example in b inside the prototype there are username and password from a they should be outside and with the username from b not the original from a

Comment: You need to put all the data in the prototype if u want them to be shared properties that can be overridden.. like so : [http://jsfiddle.net/fantop4d/z62eA/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/fantop4d/z62eA/5/)

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. `result.protorype[key]` should be `result.prototype[key]`